# How to change the git bash username on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, windows-7

Assume that my username in Windows 7 is Caesar. When I open Git Bash I am greeted with something like

> Caesar@COMPUTER-NAME$

Is it possible to change my username to be lowercase (so that it agrees with various Linux servers I have):

> caesar@COMPUTER-NAME$

P.S. In cygwin, one can edit `/etc/passwd` in an obvious way to achieve this, but there is no such file for git bash (might be useful).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the ssh_config facility to specify a different username. See an ssh_config manpage for details, but briefly:

Create the file `~/.ssh/config`, and put just this line in it:

```
User caesar
```

If you have different usernames for different hosts, you can use the Host setting to specify different usernames, including the default one:

```
Host rome1
  User caesar
Host rome2
  User brutus
Host *
  User romeo
```

Normally, the `~/.ssh/config` file has to have mode 600, but that doesn't seem to be necessary for the Git windows version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't work. What can be reason?

Comment: @dondublon: if Linux, did you do `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`? It will be ignored otherwise. If not that, can you provide an example, or perhaps ask your own SO question?

Answer (score 12):

To change **windows username** also with **Git bash username** *(not for upper case)*:

- Open Command prompt
- Enter netplwiz
- Select the windows user account and click the Properties button
- Enter the new name for the account
- Save and restart your computer

Comment: To run "netplwiz" on a git bash terminal, I had to open it with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 3):

This thread is a few years old, but the correct answer is to change the value of the variable that holds that information.

If you modify the git-prompt.sh script a bit (for me, this is located in *c:\Program Files(x86)\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh*), you can make the title anything you want.

Note: You will need to run VS Code, Notepad ++ or similar as administrator to write back to this directory.

```
PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
```

example:

```
...
PS1="$PS1"'STACKOVERFLOW@ABC '    # user@host<space>
...
PS1="$PS1"'LOL '                  # show MSYSTEM
...
```

console:

```
STACKOVERFLOW@ABC LOL /
$
```

Answer (score 1):

It is based on what is set to the `$PS1`, which is what is used to display your prompt. The username@computername part would have been generated by a value like `\u@\h$`. I am not aware of easy ways to make `\u` value lowercase, but in your profile, you can do some processing with the username and use the necessary lowercase value ( or anything) that you want  and set it to the `$PS1`

Comment: This only changes the display.  He wants the username itself changed so that it interacts nicely with other servers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly what you want, but you can also clone/edit your remotes to have the URL with the username included. Ex.: git clone ssh://caesar@myprojecturl.git

Comment: I am aware. This is what I was actually trying to avoid :)

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you can achieve this by creating a file at `C:\Users\{userName}\.config\git\` and inside this folder you can create a file with name `git-prompt.sh`.

Inside this file you can write following code

```
USER="Dev"                     # You can use any name you want to see in terminal

PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
PS1="$PS1"'$USER@\h '          # user@host<space>
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
    COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
    if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
    then
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
        . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
        PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
    fi
fi
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
```

This file is basically used by git. If this file exits, git will look for this file else it will use default config present at
`C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh` - for x86/32 bit system
and
`c:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh` for a standard x64 bit system.

This above code snippet is also used from same file.