# Wrong username in console after username change in Windows

Tags: windows, git, console, git-bash

I had a Windows (Windows 10) local userprofile with an umlaut (ä) in it. With this I got problems while using vagrant in the Git Bash console. After some research I changed the username of my local profile (replaced the ä with ae). I also changed the name of the users folder and reinstalled vagrant after this. Everything works fine now except the fact, that the username which is shown in Git Bash is the same as before (with ä in it). But the path is correct (with ae).

I tried to change the username with `git config --global user.name` but this had no effect on the name displayed. I also reinstalled Git.

This is annoying (even tho it has no effect on anything). Why is that and how can I change it? Is there a way to reset it completely (besides a reinstallation)?

Because I'm not sure if I use the correct terms I mean this (the bold word) with username:

**MyNameWithÄ**@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 ~

And I should also mention that I use Git only locally and I don't know if it even has something todo with Git Bash.

Kind regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the git bash username on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816131/how-to-change-the-git-bash-username-on-windows)

Comment: @vcsjones I saw this post but it was no help for my problem

Comment: @Tim can you explain why?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't know if I get the other question and answers wrong but the username itself is changed (via git config). But the name which is displayed by the console is not. For me it sounds wrong to modify the ssh config to achive this. I thought I could delete some Git config files to reset Git completely.

Comment: `MyNameWithÄ@COMPUTERNAME` --- I don't think this has anything to do with git.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, this could be true. I hope to get some tips where this comes from. My first thought was Git.

Comment: Typical unix problem, lots of little hidden config files spread all over the disk and every program has to figure it out by itself.  Just search the disk for the string, start with `.*.*`

Answer (score 1):

Git Bash takes the user from file /etc/passwd. To change it do:

```
mkpasswd > /etc/passwd
```

This step was necessary for me on Windows 10 because the file did not exist in that location. Administrator privileges are necessary (open Git Bash as admin).

Then change the file with your favourite editor (for instance vim). Substitute the old username with the new one.

Reopen Git Bash to see changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the proper solution I have one ugly hack in mind.

Git-bash stores it's prompt configuration in `/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh`.
When you open that file you should have this line:

```
PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
```

Replacing `\u` here with your name should do the trick. So it would be:

```
PS1="$PS1"'JohnDoe@\h '             # user@host<space>
```

In order to see the changes you need to restart git-bash.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it's of course not the best solution. There must be a file in which the old name is stored. If it's still the old name after reinstalling Git I think the name is stored in a config file which gets not deleted on deinstallation. But where?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, I found out that this has something to do with the Administrator Name and Device Name (Press Window + I > Settings > System > About > Device Name).